Help moving lost funds from Safe(Wallet) on X Layer
Situation: I sent WETH to my Arbitrum Safe(Wallet), but on X Layer. Now I am trying to recover the funds and send them to an address I can control.
What I have done so far: I have recreated the same Safe(Wallet) using a guide and can now see the same wallet address, but on X Layer within Safe(Wallet). I can SEE the funds and have sent another text tx and it works. I have installed Docker in order to run CLI.
Problem: The Safe(Wallet) UI will not let me send funds OUT of this X Layer wallet, because it wasn't created with their UI. Can someone please type out the CLI commands in order to get my funds sent back out to a different wallet? This is beyond my ability at this point and I need assistance. I don't know how to find the X Layer endpoint URL and all of that either.
Thank you in advance.

You can follow the steps I mentioned in this question: ETH address under OP Network
Hope it helps! Best, Louis

Hello. No, this does not help as it is related to OP and I have stated that I do not have the technical know-how to make this work for X Layer. I do not know how to code any commands and I do not know where to get X Layer URLs to make this all work. Funds are still stuck.

You will need to follow these exact steps stated in my answer except:


at step 4 instead of the first command you will type safe-cli <YOUR_SAFE_ADDRESS> <XLAYER_NODE_URL>, where XLAYER_NODE_URL is the URL of an X Layer node that can broadcast the transaction (https://github.com/okx/xlayer-node/blob/dev/docs/running_local.md).


at step 5 you will type send_erc20 <ADDRESS THAT WILL RECEIVE THE TOKENS> 0x5a77f1443d16ee5761d310e38b62f77f726bc71c <NUMBER OF TOKENS TO SEND> instead.


The rest of the answer should be followed as is. Can you confirm it worked? Thanks in advance
